# Syncing countdown timer and progress bar

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown and a rounded progress bar. Countdown is ticking till a specific date and rounded progress bar is filling for 60s then starts over, but my problem is that it is not synced. When I refresh the page, countdown is working correctly but progress bar refreshes. If countdown is at 30s, progress bar is supposed to bo half-filled, but instead it starts over. Im a beginner in Javascript, so I dont realy know how to sync them. Could anyone help me solve this problem?
I have 2 fiddles, I could not figure out how to have this 2 javascript scripts together working, so they are on 2 seperates fiddles. I would really love some help on this matter.
Countdown - https://jsfiddle.net/BrsJsk/aa8a10sy/2/

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
 
  var t = endtime - new Date().getTime();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date("Jul 22, 2017 06:00:00").getTime();
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
   <div id="clockdiv">
      <p1 class="dayss"><span class="num days">34</span> days</p1>
      <p1 class="hourss"><span class="num hours">16</span> hours</p1>
      <p1 class="secondss"><span class="num seconds">1</span> secs</p1>
      <p1 class="minutess"><span class="num minutes">19</span> mins</p1>
    </div>
```

Progress bar - https://jsfiddle.net/BrsJsk/2xm2nhw3/

```js
{
      var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
        quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
        quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
        quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
        quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
        counter = document.querySelector('.counter');


      var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 600);

      function incrementProg() {
        progress = parseInt(progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'));
        progress = ((progress + 1) % 100);
        if (progress === 0) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
          quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
        }
        progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
        counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
        setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
      }

      function setPie(progress) {
        /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
        if (progress <= 25) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');

        }

        /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
        else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
        }

        /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
        else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
        }

        /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
        else if (progress > 75 && progress < 100) {
          quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
          quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
          quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
          quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
          progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #c8c9cb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}

div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
}

.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}

.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
  /* invisible at -90deg */
}

.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  /* invisible at 90deg */
}


/* Just for demo */

div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<div data-progress="0">
        <div class="quad1"></div>
        <div class="quad2"></div>
        <div class="quad3"></div>
        <div class="quad4"></div>
        <div class='counter'></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to link the `second` value of the `countdown` to the `progress` of the `progress bar`.

As following;

```js
var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
  quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
  quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
  quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
  quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
  counter = document.querySelector('.counter');

function incrementProg(progress) {
  if (progress === 0) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
    quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
  }
  counter.textContent = progress // set countdown timer's value
  setPie(60 - progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
}

function setPie(progress) {
  if (progress < 15) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 15) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  } else if (progress >= 15 && progress < 30) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 15) * (90 / 15) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  } else if (progress >= 30 && progress < 45) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 30) * (-90 / 15) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  } else if (progress >= 45 && progress < 60) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
    quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 45) * (90 / 15) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  }
}

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = endtime - new Date().getTime();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
    incrementProg(t.seconds);
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date("Jul 22, 2017 06:00:00").getTime();
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #c8c9cb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}

div > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
}

.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}

.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
  /* invisible at -90deg */
}

.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  /* invisible at 90deg */
}


/* Just for demo */

div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <p1 class="dayss"><span class="num days">34</span> days</p1>
  <p1 class="hourss"><span class="num hours">16</span> hours</p1>
  <p1 class="minutess"><span class="num minutes">19</span> mins</p1>
  <p1 class="secondss"><span class="num seconds">1</span> secs</p1>
</div>

<div data-progress="0">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
  <div class='counter'></div>
</div>
```

I had to modify small bits to make it work well with 60 seconds, and as you can see it works well. You can modify the printed second on progress bar, currently it is reverse of the countdown.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I cant figure out how you made it work? Also, what did you do so it goes reverse?

Comment: @Brs As I explained, I just linked the `incrementProg` function inside, at the end of the `initializeClock` function, I couldn't explain all the details because the code is too much. The reverse amount thing is because your code was starting from 100 down to 0, now it is doing the same from 60 to 0. I modified the answer to reverse that count to have same value with countdown's second value. So in short I've done a mapping from 100 to 60, in your progress bar logic.

Comment: Yes, Id like it to go as in my JS fiddle. You made it work like it is supposed to work and I thank you for that, but It really shoult not go reverse. If you could maybe make the progress bar not go reverse, that would be great! 
Im trying to figure out how you did it

Comment: @burequete 
Yes I see, but the blue rounded progress bar goes the other way around. From left to right, but it needs to go from right to left.

I hope you understand what I mean